# Report with JasperReports with database connection

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports

I'm trying to make a report with JasperReports containing the result of the queries to a database. I followed some tutorials and I wrote the code. The part which the database connection it's ok, it works:

"Get connection ... 
Get connection oracle.jdbc.driver.************
Done!", but when I'm trying to run the class with the report, I face some exceptions:

1) Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files : E:\Fc\Java\hws\L9again\StyledTextReport_1462019818479_424906.java;

2)Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified;

3)Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

My code for the part with the report is:

```
package org.o7;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException; 
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.ExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.OutputStreamExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimplePdfExporterConfiguration;

public class JavaCallJasperReport {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException,
        ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String reportSrcFile =     "C:/jasperreport/StyledTextReport/StyledTextReport.jrxml";

    // First, compile jrxml file.
    JasperReport jasperReport =   JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSrcFile);

    Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

    // Parameters for report
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            parameters, conn);

    // Make sure the output directory exists.
    File outDir = new File("C:/jasperoutput");
    outDir.mkdirs();

    // PDF Exportor.
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    ExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(print);
    // ExporterInput
    exporter.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

    // ExporterOutput
    OutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(
            "C:/jasperoutput/FirstJasperReport.pdf");
    // Output
    exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);

    //
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();

    System.out.print("Done2!");
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try putting jdt-compiler.jar  in  you classpath.let me know if you have problem doing that

Comment: I still have the warnings, but the report it was created with no errors. Thanks

Comment: i am glad i have been able to help and thank for upvoting

Comment: any hints how to make a query report using the above code?

Comment: please can u explain further?

Comment: I might be able to help but i need some information on what exactly you want to do

Comment: I connected to the database and I execute a query which is diplayed on the console, and for this query I want to do a report(using  the code which I just posted in this topic). For now, the report it is created, but it is empty. I want make this report containing the result of the querie.

Comment: please check out the link. I think it might help u.Let me know if it helps or not.we are in this together     http://www.coderanch.com/t/523321/open-source/JasperReport-Dynamic-SQL-Query-queryString

Comment: yes, it is useful..but i don't understand why the report is empty..i have changed the jrxml file twice(with simplier code) but it's still empty

Comment: please are u using ireport? to design the jrxml file?

Comment: may be the file is misformed.do you have ireport install locally? so that we can debug to see if the file is indeed misformed.